# Join data frames using reduce2() in R

Tags: r, reduce

Here's [a link](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#multiple-inputs) that introduces the use of `reduce2()`.

Hadley introduced the example,

> you might have a list of data frames that you want to join together, and the variables you use to join will vary from element to element.

I can't quite imagine what the situation is.

I understood the `reduce2()` because I understood the example in [a link](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html)

```r
x <- list(c(0, 1), c(2, 3), c(4, 5))
y <- list(c(6, 7), c(8, 9))
reduce2(x, y, paste)
#> [1] "0 2 6 4 8" "1 3 7 5 9"
```

But the described example by Hadley is hard to imagine for me.

Can anyone describe the example?

Comment: do you not understand how the function works? or are you trying to come up with a real world problem to apply it to?

Comment: my take would be: you have a list of data.frames as the first, longer argument. The second argument, one element shorter, would contain the mappings for successive joins between the accumulating data.frame and the next element.  As the doc says, a specialized function

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a real world problem to apply: `df1 <- data.frame(x = c(0, 2, 4), y = c(1, 3, 5));
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(6, 8), b = c(7, 9)); lst <- list(df1, df2)` and using `reduce2()` to stack it? I can't understand the situation. @jenesaisquoi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Working Example

Here is an example that Hadley could have had in his mind.
Imagine, we have a **list** of those **data frames**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1=data.frame(a = runif(10),b = runif(10),a_0 = c(1,2,2,5,3,1,2,2,5,3))
df2=data.frame(a = runif(5),c = runif(5),b_0 = c(4,1,4,1,4))
df3=data.frame(c = runif(3),d = runif(3),a = runif(3),c_0 = c(5,1,2))
df4=data.frame(b = runif(5),a = runif(5),e = runif(5),d_0 = c(5,1,5,3,1))

lst = list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```

Now, we want to reduce those data frames by left_joining them two-by-two which is **not** based on common column/columns; in our case, that would have been column `a`. Instead, we are interested in left_joining the data frames based on given pairs presented in `by_list`:

```
by_list=list(c("a_0"="b_0"),c("a_0"="c_0"),c("a_0"="d_0"))
```

When we call `reduce2()` function, we get the following output:

```
reduce2(lst,by_list,left_join)
```

[image: The Output of the Function Call]

Here we can observe that this produces a list with all long-formated rows from common elements present in column `a_0` of `df1` and its corresponding pairs in other data frames. ***Note also***, that suffixes of `a.x`,`a.y`,`a.x.x`,`a.y.y`, for example, indicate/separate those same-named columns from nested join operations that **were not** used for any join operation.

Comment: It would be nicer if `set.seed()` supplied before the `df`s. Still, Thank you so much. Understood!